# Converting Json string array to list

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I got the below JSON.Stringify data from ajax call to c# code. I am trying to loop through each country like. But I am unable to make countryList as List or array from resultant string from ajax call. String returned to controller is 
["Germany","Brazil","United States"] while debugging but it is showing with reverse slashes and It fails reading in loop.

```
 foreach (var cntry in countryList){
//my code
}
```

I tried the below

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try parsing the JSON first. Here's how:

```
foreach (var cntry in Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(countryList))
{
    //my code
}
```

You need to NuGet "Newtonsoft.Json" to get this to work.

Comment: any other option apart from getting Newtonsoft please?

Comment: @Kurkula - You would have to write a JSON parser yourself or use an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Using **System.Text.Json**:

```
var countriesJsonAsString = "[\"Germany\", \"Brazil\", \"United States\"]";
foreach (var entry in System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(countriesJsonAsString))
{
    // my code here, entry will contain the name of the country.
}
```